# bit.ly redirect not functioning properly

Tags: redirect, hyperlink, web, bit.ly

I have been going back and forth with my dev teams today to determine an issue that has come up. It appears that links shortened by bit.ly are not being directed to the proper URL on mobile devices only. This URL http://bit.ly/1aRvnqH will take you to the appropriate place on a desktop computer, but put it into a mobile device browser on your phone and it is broken. The URL that the mobile device renders is a very old link from our old web structure from more than a year ago.

Further it is appending a GA tag for our affiliate program platform as well as a reference code that does not exist in our affiliate program.

My dev guys think it may be something to do with this new deep linking on mobile that bit.ly recently rolled out. When I called bit.ly, they said they've never heard or seen of this before and asked I send an email to their support group which I've done.

Was hoping someone here may have some ideas as well.

Thanks in advance.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

*DISCLAIMER:  I'm a developer at Bitly*

This is a bug caused by our on-going [affiliate test](http://support.bitly.com/customer/portal/articles/1880538-bitly-affiliate-test?b_id=5612).

We're pushing out a fix for this link now and it should be working properly within the next 30 minutes.

If other links stop working for you in the future, please contact us at support@bit.ly or http://support.bitly.com and we'd be happy to look into it.